# Getting file path of uploaded file in FineUploader

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

I am using FineUploader to upload files. I am using their php-traditional-server

https://github.com/FineUploader/php-traditional-server

https://docs.fineuploader.com/quickstart/03-setting_up_server.html

I am also using the jquery.fine-uploader.js

This gets initialised in the page during a loop so that each "room" gets a Fine Uploader like this

```
<div id="<?php echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "_", strtoupper($room->room_name)); ?>"></div>


    <script>
        $('#<?php echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", "_", strtoupper($room->room_name)); ?>').fineUploader({
            template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/fine-uploader/server/endpoint.php'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            }
        });
    </script>
```

I have this working fine, it uploads files perfectly. It is the last piece of the puzzle I am stuck on. What I want to know is how to get the file path of the uploaded file? I can see that the files are uploading and can see the path via ftp. What I would like is some sort of "when complete" that gives me the file path as a javascript variable. I would then use this to append the form with a hidden input containing the file path. I know exactly how to do the latter part. What I need to know is how do I get the file path on success of a uploaded file?

Any help would be truly appreciated

**EDIT**

I have worked out I can get the filename from qq.getFilename, now if I could only get the UID my problem would be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked it out!

I needed to add a callback onComplete. In this example I just console.log the response which contains the uid and file name. From this I can build the url I need

```
$('#id-of-fine-uploader-div').fineUploader({
            template: 'qq-template-gallery',
            request: {
                endpoint: '/fine-uploader/server/endpoint.php'
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    waitingPath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath: '/fine-uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            },
            callbacks: {
                onComplete: function(id, name, responseJSON, maybeXhr) {console.log(responseJSON)}
            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using the jQuery wrapper here? It doesn't look like you need to. Note that the wrapper will be removed entirely in v6.0.